Issue with the pytorch interpolate
I am new to model and deep learning training , In my training section i am trying to find the loss of the segmentation of the image , so in here before cross entropy loss calculation i have used interpolate to downsize the image which came out of the model,
Here the size of the image from the model which came out is (5,36,180,320)
here the 5 is the batch size , 36 is the channel size and the 180, 320 is the h x w
The target image shape is (5,1,180,320)
the 5 is the batch size , 1 is the channel , 180 x 320 is the h x w
the target image has 1 channel value from 0 to 35 which is number of available segmenatation
Now i am downsizing to the image to (1,180,320)
so it can match the target image size but the issue in here is
i used it like this
outs = F.interpolate(out, target.size()[1:] , mode = 'bilinear' , aligin_corners = False).squeeze(dim = 1 )
# out -> is the image
# size is mentioning (1,180,320)
crit_loss = crit(outs , target.squeeze(dim=1))
# here crit is cross entropy loss
loss += (loss_coeff * crit_loss)

i get the error

Input and the output must have the same number of spatial dimentions, but got input with spatial dimensions of [180,320] and output size of torch.Size([1,180,320]).please provide input tensor

I have tried all the the ways that i came up with nothing worked, if i use the sizr as (180,320) inside the interpolate i get the shape outs as 36,180,320 which cause issue at the crit what should i do where it does went wrong, please help me

F.interpolate only defined the bilinear mode for last 2 channels of a 4-D tensor. For cross entropy loss, you would like the tensor to be logits, not the index of the class. If you want to take the class index, you can do the torch.argmax but beware as this is non differentiable.
